# List variable concept in python

Tags: python

Question regarding list in python: I have one program in that list are generating and assigning to a different variable but still getting the same output for two variable...Not able to understand the functionality.

Code:

```
def extendList (val, list=[]):
    list.append(val)
    return list
list1 = extendList (10)
list2 = extendList (123, [])
list3 = extendList ('a')

print list1, list2, list3
```

Comment: hard to say without seeing an expected and actual output, but I suspect your may be getting tripped up by pythons mutable default arguments. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: Here's another link that I think does a great job: [click here](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm)

Comment: System output is:  [10, 'a'] [123] [10, 'a']
And my output is: [10], [123], [10,'a']

Comment: @PoojaRastogi Read the link I've shared. It explains this behavior

Comment: Hi Rushabha, Thanks for the link.. I have read the article but my situation is different because in my I am using different variables to save the values. For 1st variable list1 storing 10 into it but system output is [10, 'a']  at last.
if we separately put print command after list1 it will give output 10 only

Comment: Please look to below code and corresponding output. And see the difference in system output:
def extentList (val, list=[]):
 list.append(val)
 return list
list1 = extentList (10)
print list1
list2 = extentList (123, [])
list3 = extentList ('a')
print list3
print list1, list2, list3


System Output:
C:\Users\rastogip\Documents\Python>excersice1.py
[10]
[10, 'a']
[10, 'a'] [123] [10, 'a']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the command

```
def extentList (val, list=[]):
```

the list variable is initialized only *once* - after the first calling it remains as it is.

Replace your code with

```
def extentList (val, list=None):
    if list is None:
        list = []
    list.append(val)
    return list
```

See [Default parameter values are evaluated when the function definition is executed](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#index-20) in the Python Tutorial:

> ```
> ... if the function modifies the object (e.g. by appending an item to a list),
> the default value is in effect modified...
> ```

---

Put `print list1`, immediately after `list1 = ...` and `print list2` immediately after `list2 = ...` to see that `list1` and `list3` are two different names for the *same* list - you used the *default parameter* for creating `list1` and `list3`, and this *default parameter* - the list - is initialized (i. e. created, too) *only once*:

```
list1 = extendList (10)
print list1

list2 = extendList (123, [])
print list2

list3 = extendList ('a')

print list1, list2, list3
```

The output:

> ```
> [10]
> [123]
> [10, 'a'] [123] [10, 'a']
> ```

Comment: can you please explain in my case why the output for list1 and list3 are same at last, How list are working into it. Because if we put print list1 after list1 variable it will print 10 only.

Comment: @PoojaRastogi, I expanded my answer.

Comment: Thanks Marian... I understood clearly now.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because of the default list value. The list value remains the same at each calll of your function

> "Python’s default arguments are evaluated once when the function is defined, not each time the function is called (like it is in say, Ruby). This means that if you use a mutable default argument and mutate it, you will and have mutated that object for all future calls to the function as well."

from [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/)